# I can resolve the tsconfig.json problem with keyof T

Tags: angular, typescript

I have declared a variable:

```
const resource = {
  type: 'custom',
  rendererFn: this.getResourceDisplayValue,
};
```

In models.ts I declared:

```
rendererFn: (row: T, column: keyof T) => string;
```

and the function is:

```
getResourceDisplayValue(
  row: SynopsisHeader,
  column: keyof SynopsisHeader
): string {
  return 'str';
}
```

I have the next message:

Type '(row: SynopsisHeader, column: keyof SynopsisHeader) => string' is not assignable to type '(row: any, column: string | number | symbol) => string'.
Types of parameters 'column' and 'column' are incompatible.
Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type 'keyof SynopsisHeader'.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'keyof SynopsisHeader'.
[image]

Could you help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: can't reproduce [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAZQgOwPZQM4EsMAkYCGAJjAE5wC8cA3qHHMgQLYwBccGYpWyA5qAF9QoAGYBXZAGMwWVMji8YYAEowMqMaUkwAIjigAbAhABqBA2JgAKOnFKoA7uyRpMOfMTIAaW5NQWmZHYAaxgIVBFEFHRsPEISUlAASnZObj4aW1IlTXkAcjS8gG5BYXBoeFV1TW0AHgAVAD5KTJB6SFh2PMkxTlQmPJ82uxhkBLIAMSC4K3snOHqvOD8A6dDwyPqkyma0nn4QIRBQP2ROEeqtNjgqjSvalxj3eLJmqlphjuvu3rB+wayo3GpCm7EUKjUd20egwhmMZgsMCGAhKxxAQA), please provide minimal example